# Submitting forms using requirejs submits about 800 times

Tags: javascript, html, forms, requirejs

In a current project we are trying to switch to requrejs, but I have some trouble submitting a simple form. Each time the form submit buuton will be clicked, the form stores about 800 times. I have a token in the form, that will be deleted once the form has been stored (PHP based storing process). I have already tried to use a data-attribute to prevent double submitting

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
    if($(this).data('submitted') === true) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    $(this).data('submitted', true);
});
```

I even tried to use a global variable setting to true/false or some timeout functions and using the domReady module by requirejs and making all fields readonly/disable buttons. Nothing changed. In all cases the form submits about 800 times before it cancels submitting. Please, does anyone have an idea whythis forms submits too much?

Thanks, Karl

**EDIT**
My requirejs config (reduced the configuration since the filenames doesn't matter here and the config is big.)

```
    var config = {
    baseUrl: 'http://example.com/scripts/',
    paths: {
        app1: 'app/app1',
        app2: 'app/app2',
        lib1: 'libs/lib1'
    },
    waitSeconds: 20
}


requirejs.config(config);
// initializes the main page, loading page-dependent modules
require(['initial', "libs/domReady!"], function(app) {
    app.init();
});
// the module app, a bit reduced. This will be loaded during the module loader and initialized
define("app/modules/form", [
    'jquery',
    'libs/domReady',
    'document',
    'notifier'
], function($, domReady, doc) {
    var module = {
        needInit: true,
        initialized: false,
        init: function() {
            if(this.initialized) return false;
            this.initialized = true;
            $("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
                    var $form = $(this);
                    if($form.data('submitted')) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    }
                    $form.data('submitted', true);
                    // normally would validate here. this has been removed to reduce possible script errors
                    return true;
                });
        }
    }

});
```

The app.init() called in main-script has a module loader that loads modules from data-attributes and prevents double loading modules, that have already been loaded.

### EDIT 2

I have now included an event-handler lister, which logs me only 1 event-handler to the form. Think, so the event handler is not loaded multiple times?

Comment: Don't try and hack it to prevent double submissions, find out the root cause. It sounds like you may have architected your `requirejs` setup to include that piece of code many times (and, thus, attach the `submit` handler multiple times). Can you check the JS code loaded on your page and verify that the submit handler is only present once?

Comment: I have tried, what I can: mthe script is loaded once. I have validated, the init function of the module only fires once. How can I prevent requirejs another way loading a module multiple times?

Comment: We have no way of knowing without seeing your requirejs code.

Comment: @KarlAftring RequireJS modules are singleton,. It is very unlikely that you'd get multiple instances of the *same* module by accident. You added that you used a tool that can list event handlers. Unless this tool is made to handle jQuery specially, it will be misleading. jQuery installs one handler per event type, even if the dev installs 100 different handlers of the same time,  and then does its own internal dispatching to all the handlers the dev installed.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like @Adam and @Louis both have been right. I was too much focused on the form and its events and did not recognized the rest of the page. After a long research and more testings I found an external plugin used on the page (not inside the form) that has hooked into the form. After disabling the plugin (or at least changing to a new one) The form submits as expected. Many thanks for your suggestions where to search!